# Git add errors: Could not open directory: Permission Denied

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I am using windows 10. When I type the command "git add ." in my Git Bash I keeping getting this message as shown below:

```
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/ElevatedDiagnostics/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/History/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.IE5/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Music/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Pictures/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Videos/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied
```

Comment: What is your current working directory? `C:\Users\<username>`? I'm afraid you are using Git command on a wrong path for a long time...

Comment: @GenoChen It must be like that `%UserProfile%`

Comment: @iBug Agree. These folder are likely a home directory under Windows.

Comment: @GenoChen   Many thanks for your response /c/Users/Mateo

Comment: @MateoChiyangi That's it. Why you execute Git command on this path...?

Comment: @GenoChen What path should I be using? I'm new to Git

Comment: @MateoChiyangi The path of your code project. You may have many code project in many separated folder.

Comment: How to how start a new project in Git? Here is what I am trying to do:   1. Create a text file called HelloWorld.md
Add the line "## This is a markdown file" (without the quotation marks) to the document (without the quotation marks)

2.Push the document to the datasciencecoursera repo you created on Github

3. Submit the link to the HelloWorld.md file on your Github repo.

Answer (score 12):

In case someone else comes here when searching for this error, and they are **definitely** on the correct path already, this issue may be caused by unsaved files in the working directory - try making sure all files are saved, and closing any IDE that is open

Comment: "Try making sure all files are saved, and closing any IDE that is open." - This helped. I had a file open in my text comparing tool. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are running Git subcommand on a unexpected directory.

Most of Git subcommand are path-dependent. In most cases these subcommand treats the *current working directory* as Git root, and do Git operations **inside** Git root.

For regular usage, we treat the root directory for code project as Git root. Multiple code project results in multiple folder, and multiple corresponding Git roots. Use *current working directory* to specify them.

The default current working directory is called Home directory, which is `~` or mostly `/home/<user>` or `/root` in *nix, or `C:\Users\<user>` (non-Administrator) or `C:\Windows\System32` (Administrator) in Windows > 7 or `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>` in Windows <= XP.

If you didn't specify current working directory (with command `cd`), all the Git operations are operating your home directory. This can be harmful under some situations. Small disaster is just like what you met, big disaster can be something like you accidently uploaded your private file in GitHub or something equivalent after you realized that.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed response. How do I make sure I'm in the right directory?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the same problem only get root access running the terminal as a administrator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

1. First Go to that path and DELETE the .git repository.(In your File Manager)
2. Open Git Bash at Required Folder(It means in Folder by clicking right click)
3. Create .git repository by giving command ($ git init).
4. By this there is one .git file will be created (.git file will created in your required folder).
5. Now Check git status.
   Hurrrrrrrrrrayyyyy!