# When I type 'touch index.html' on git bash

Tags: git

i get

```
$ git status
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied
On branch master
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. Also what OS are you using?

Comment: Did you create a git repo in your home folder? (`%userprofile%`)

Comment: Is this perhaps on a Windows machine?  I've seen the permissions get really wonky on windows machines with git, and get resolved when just doing a full restart...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git add errors: Could not open directory: Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932041/git-add-errors-could-not-open-directory-permission-denied)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+warning%3A+could+not+open+directory+%27Cookies%2F%27%3A+Permission+denied

Answer (score 1):

If index.html is in a folder which is supposed to represent a Git repository, you should make sure that folder has a .git/ subfolder in it, which will make said folder a proper Git repository

```
cd C:\path\to\my\file
git init .
```

Then a `git status` will not show all those Windows system folder.
As commented, make sure you don't have a `%USERPROFILE%\.git\` directory already present, as that would make your *all* User profile a "(giant) Git repository"