# Gitlab Could not open directory

Tags: git, gitlab, repository

I just clonned a repository from gitlab, just by writting git status shows:
warning: could not open directory 'Menú Inicio/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Mis documentos/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
.................... and so on.
But also
Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
../../.anaconda/
../../.android/
../../.bash_history, etc

I am really lost here. I worked once before with git but never happened this. How can I solve this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells that git doesn't have permission to read from paths it shouldn't have access to. You're probably running `git status` from an *unexpected directory* where git has not be initialized. See also this [Stack Overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932041/git-add-errors-could-not-open-directory-permission-denied).

My guess is that you have cloned the repo in `Mis documentos` and not in a sub-directory. You can figure this out by finding in which directory the hidden `.git` folder is located.

Comment: It was exactly that! Thank you